# Is there a standard way to create the blue resize handles?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Is there a standard way to create the blue resize handles? Such as what you see in "Pages" when you resize graphics.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know but it shouldnt be too hard to do.

Create a view large enough for the image and a border to add the UIbuttons. Add the image view. Use Animation kit to change the size and location of both  views simultaneously.